# i2c pin declaration in device tree file?

Tags: embedded-linux, device-tree

Any one can help to figure out what the below code mean

especially 0x80000000 important of this value in below device tree node

```
i2c-gpio-1 {
        pinctrl_smx6_i2c_gpio_1: i2c-gpio-1grp-smx6 {
            fsl,pins = <
                /* SCL GPIO */
                MX6QDL_PAD_GPIO_6__GPIO1_IO06   0x80000000
                /* SDA GPIO */
                MX6QDL_PAD_KEY_COL2__GPIO4_IO10 0x80000000
            >;
        };
    };
```

Comment: Please state which CPU your board is using, this will allow to refer to the correct device tree binding documentation.

Comment: I am using kontron smarc-samx6i board and using a processor of NXP imx6q That device tree node belongs to yocto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This device tree node defines the pinmux configuration for two signals of the imx6q processor on the board to be used as GPIOs (for a bitbanged i2c controller).

The relevant documentation file is: [fsl,imx-pinctrl.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/pinctrl/fsl,imx-pinctrl.txt)

Especially, this part is relevant here:

> Required properties for pin configuration node:
>
> - fsl,pins: each entry consists of 6 integers and represents the mux and config setting for one pin. The first 5 integers  are specified using a PIN_FUNC_ID macro,
>     which can be found in imx*-pinfunc.h under device tree source folder.
>     The last integer CONFIG is the pad setting value like pull-up on this
>     pin. And that's why fsl,pins entry looks like  in
>     the example below.
>
> Bits used for CONFIG: NO_PAD_CTL(1 << 31): indicate this pin does not
>   need config.

The two PIN_FUNC_ID macros

> MX6QDL_PAD_GPIO_6__GPIO1_IO06, MX6QDL_PAD_KEY_COL2__GPIO4_IO10

are directly taken from this file: [imx6q-pinfunc.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6q-pinfunc.h)

The 0x80000000 value next to these macros is the NO_PAD_CTL(1 << 31) macro from above. This means that that the pins are not configured with the pinmux possibilities detailed there: [fsl,imx6q-pinctrl.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/pinctrl/fsl,imx6q-pinctrl.txt)